# Change 'components only' in navigation guard

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I want to see if I can exchange my components (one in 'default' router-view and another in 'navDrawer' router-view) before the launch of the page. 'Exchanging' would just be derogative goal to what I actually want to achieve.

Eventually, I would want to pass an argument into the component before loading the whole page itself but apparently the component is loaded through this router and I want to pre-check(with or without guard) before I decide what props to pass into the components.

Here is my `routers/index.js`

`Landing` & `LandingButtonBar` are components.

```
1 export default new Router({
2  routes: [
3    {
4      path: '/',
5        name: 'Landing',

6        components: {
7          default: Landing,
8          navDrawer: LandingButtonBar
9        },

10       // Guard
11       beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
           // put some conditions here to invoke the next line.
12         next({
13           // path: '/',  // this will obviously cause a recursion
14           components: {
15             default: LandingButtonBar,
16             navDrawer: Landing
             }
           })
         }
       }
     ]
   })
```

Everything works as expected. But I also hoped that the components would exchange each other before loading. Is this possible using **within routes**?

**Attempt 1**:

Self directing the guard would work for like 0.01 sec but then it would get caught up in an infinite loop. i.e. uncommenting line no 13. Also removing the 'path' attribute would have no effect after loading the page. Failed.

Comment: You'll probably want to look at [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Comment: Without `path` in the `next()`. There seems to be no other way to invoke component change. And with `path: '/'` It just seem to get stuck in this loop forever.

Comment: For now I just resolved to using Dynamic component and a different path. This question seems like a dead-lock question. Should I delete it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve doing this exactly? I've never seen a situation where manipulating the components within a route like this was necessary, so I'm genuinely curious what you're going for in the end here.

Comment: I've updated the second paragraph. 

Basically, I have a 'NavToolbar' that changes(in named router-view) according to the given route path but what if in the **same** route path I need to pass an additional parameters(like color = blue) to the NavToolbar (lets say that would happen when auth fails). I would prefer that the NavToolbar adjust according to that.

I did realize that this was unneccesary & I could've just used Vuex but I was just curious as well.

Comment: I see, in these cases I definitely use vuex and then render the navbar items using `v-for` as they're definitely in my layout/menu module. Sounds like you're on the right path now.